# Vertical stacked bar chart using SharePoint List

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, chart.js, sharepoint-2013

I have to create a stacked bar chart using the SharePoint complex list data using REST, JavaScript. The main problem here is i am not getting proper data sets.

Let me clear my scenario here: Suppose i am having a SharePoint-2013 list with 6 columns. I need a bar char based on column-1(Project Type) on x-axis, stacked by column-2(Technology) via count of different technology on y-axis. I am having 7 project type & 15 technology & want to processed around 200 rows with combination of them.

```
Project Java Python SharePoint .Net
A        3     5        12       1
B        4     7        6        3
C        0     9        1        0
```

I open with any Chat.js whether it is chart.js/google chart.js/highlight chat.js The only thing i need data to be dynamic means whenever user add more values to project column should added to x-axis automatically.

I am very new to this. Can anyone please help me to get this. need code part also. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide the sample code or your approach which you had tried, that would assert that you have verified its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code example for your reference:

```
<div style="width:600px;height:400px;">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var colors = ["#009EA0", "#A7A9AC", "#D15F27", "#BAD80A", "#E0AA0F", "#754760", "#373535"];
var listName = "CL26"; //Data List Name
var xAxisName="Title";
var yAxisName=["Java","Python","SharePoint","DotNet"];
$(document).ready(function() {
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                  "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items";

    //execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var myLabels=[];
            var myDataSets=[];
            $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {
                myLabels.push(item[xAxisName]);    
            });
            for(var i=0;i<yAxisName.length;i++){ 
                var myData=[];                  
                $.each(data.d.results, function(j, item) {
                    myData.push(item[yAxisName[i]]);
                });
                myDataSets.push({
                    label:yAxisName[i],
                    backgroundColor:colors[i],
                    data:myData
                });                 
            }
            buildBarChart(myLabels,myDataSets);
        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("Failed to get details");
        }
    });
});

function buildBarChart(myLabels,myDataSets){
    var barChartData = {
        labels: myLabels,
        datasets: myDataSets
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'MyProject'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
}   
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: @LZ_MSFT- thanks for your code, it is perfect. but what data i need to fetch is bit tricky. but i got the hind from your code how i can process the data now. Thanks so much..much appreciated  :)

Comment: @LZ_MSFT, I am attempting to use this code for my SP list, it displays the chart fine, can you help me to identify how to add data labels in this code? Also, if I want to re-use this script on the same SP page, but in a different web part (Script Editor), what variables should I modify? Appreciate your help!